# How to log inside Python function in PythonOperator in Airflow

Tags: airflow

I am using a PythonOperator in my Airflow DAG and I need to print something inside the operator's Python function. I tried to print but apparently it didn't work out. Not so sure that's going to work. Next I tried to pass self.log in PythonOperator but I am not sure how to pass that reference.

```
task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task1',
    python_callable=my_func,
    params={ ... },
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
)

...

def my_func(**context):
    ...
    print(some_message) # this didn't work.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way you should be logging in Airflow (and in Python in general) is through the `logging` module, that is,

```
import logging
```

on top of the DAG definition and

```
logging.info(some_message)
```

in place of the `print` statement in your `my_func` function. Other functions you can use besides `info()` (with different logging level/criticality) can be found in the Python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I just have `*** Reading local file: /home/ubuntu/airflow/logs/my_dag/log_test_task/2019-08-31T19:22:49.653712+00:00/1.log` in my logs after this (same as with a print statement). Doesn't seem to matter what the logging level is either. I'm guessing you have to specify the path the log is writing to?

Comment: Thanks! But where does this log go?