# logging inside custom operator NOT showing up in Airflow task log

Tags: airflow

Logging inside the `callable_python` function shows in the Airflow task log but the logging **inside custom `PythonOperator`** NOT.

Just found a very similar [Airflow logging doesn't show up when log from inside operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72823273/airflow-logging-doesnt-show-up-when-log-from-inside-operator)

Here is the DAG file.

```py
import pendulum
import logging

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator


airflow_log = logging.getLogger("airflow.task")
file_log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


with DAG(
    "example_logging",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2022, 10, 10, tz="UTC"),
    catchup=False,
    tags=["example"],
) as dag:
    def add(first: int, second: int) -> int:
        airflow_log.info('airflow log in add()') # showing up in airflow task log
        file_log.info('file log in add()')       # showing up in airflow task log
        return first + second

    def operator_func(task_id: str,
                      func: callable = None,
                      func_kwargs: dict = None,
                      **kwargs):
        from functools import partial
        add5 = partial(func, second=5)
        airflow_log.info('airflow log in operator_func()') # NOT showing up
        file_log.info('file log in operator_func()')      # NOT showing up
        return PythonOperator(
            task_id=task_id,
            python_callable=add5,
            op_kwargs=func_kwargs,
            **kwargs
        )

    check_logging = operator_func(
        task_id='check_logging',
        func=add,
        func_kwargs={'first': 10}
    )
```

Comment: the logs are outside the operator (its while airflow parse the DAG), The logs in the task is when it runs and here its in the definition of the Operator.